# Website URL: is directing page to a modified index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Sorry for the awkward title. Here's whats going on.. If i go to:

- URL.com/ # i see my site perfectly
- URL.com/sagfasgfr # i see my site perfectly (random noise in the url)
- URL.com/sagfas/udsudfsa # i get my index but without my CSS style (random noise in the url + sub with more noise)

I have HTACCESS configured:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://URL.com
ErrorDocument 403 http://URL.com
ErrorDocument 500 http://URL.com

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymlinks

 RewriteEngine On

</IfModule>
```

I also want to remove `.php` but the ReWrite rule I have is not working. **Please advise** By the way this site is a registration form, so ALL pages outside of the home `DIR` should NOT have direct access.

BTW: BOX IS APACHE, LINUX

rewrite rule for removing .php causes internal server error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Whoever -1 without even commenting is a j@ck@ss

Comment: I think the person rated you down because you dont show your effort in trying to solve it yourself. You could do a search you know: https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+remove+.php&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ps. wasnt me

Comment: @John I searched. I didn't find anything helpful and the code i have tried has been unsuccessful. Not exactly sure how to describe the problem, hence perhaps why my search effort is null. Perhaps instead of being a critic and assuming I didn't put forth the effort, you can actually try being helpful. As i take it (correct me if im wrong) SO is Q&A for people needing help, hence my question. SO is Not a Q&C - C being criticize or condescend (your choice). Furthermore anyone who downvotes someone without trying to help them (as long as the question isn't "write my code for me" -is a J@CK@SS

Comment: If you agree with me John, feel free to upvote my question.

Comment: I don't agree. I cannot find anything in your question that shows any effort. Tell us what you tried (maybe some configs) and where you got your information, especially since this website and google is full of answers for your question.

Comment: `RewriteCond /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/$ /$1.php` Tried that to remove the .php and didn't work

Comment: Can't find a reason why my site doesn't display correctly based on the URL and sub/folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute links for your styles and other urls, so instead of `style.css` use `http://www.yourdomain.com/path/to/style.css`.

Do this with all other urls.

If you need it to direct to the homepage, add this on your page:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != 'correcturi') {
header("Location: correcturi", 301);
exit();
}
```

Replace `correcturi` with the uri you want the page to redirect to.

**UPDATE:** I see your point. Since it doesn't exist, you are 'redirecting' the page to `url.com`. But you must remember. It won't redirect. It will just simply display that page on the same url. That's where the two pieces of code above come in handy.

Comment: Yes i know I can do that. But my question is why isn't the REDIRECT sending me to the HOMEPAGE? Its like keeping in the same `DIR` but somehow grabbing my homepage. Ty for your answer though.

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''' In that case, read my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of PHP redirects and I have that in place. The issue is arising from the HTACCESS. If I try to go to a page directly i get kicked back to the homepage. But if I put some random string in the url it shows me a modified index instead of following my HTACCESS instruction in ErrorDocument. I don't understand why my HTACCESS is not being respected.

Comment: @FA''''''''''''''''''''''' Because it's on the same document. The `.htaccess` file respects them as the same file, and therefore won't execute it correctly.

Comment: Its not a specific page that is causing the problem. The issue arises when i try to visit a `DIR` which doesn't exist -- e.g. /4523fsdfed/4325/sasafsa <- this should ErrorDoc me to url.com but instead it does nothing and just shows my index without css and without redirecting as defined in the HTACCESS

Comment: There is no document. It's just random noise in the URL

Answer (score 0):

The lines in your .htaccess don't do any rewrite, you'll need to add some RewriteRules for that. But since you claim that random url sends you to your site, I guess there must be another .htaccess (in a parent directory probably) that does the actual redirects here.

And, the css is not showing because you probably in the stylesheet href use path relative to the webroot, so when you are in a subdir this path is not valid anymore

Comment: Yeah i put a sample of my rewrite rule in the comments.. It doesn't work. also this is the parent dir. and no other HTACCESS is there